# SQL order by a function with literal values

Tags: sql, mariadb

I want to order some SQL result using the result of a calculation.
I can select this

```
SELECT sqrt( POWER(TERM_0 - -0.12985125184059143,2)) from faces f limit 3
```

So the syntax seems correct, but when I try to use it in the order by clause like this:

```sql
SELECT * from faces f limit 3
order by
sqrt( POWER(TERM_0 - -0.12985125184059143,2))
```

I get a syntax error. So what is the correct way of doing this?
I'm using mariadb as backend, not sure if that makes any difference from normal mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the order by before limit order :

```
SELECT *
from faces f 
order by sqrt( POWER(TERM_0 - -0.12985125184059143,2)) 
limit 3
```

Here is a demo:

> [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=8442ae9150a089b27102331e731f5c16)

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Stupid me

Comment: may also be able to use index of selected.  that is `... order by 1,2 limit 3;`

Comment: Yep, there may be some queries where I will have to select that calculation so I can use it not only to order, but also as a threshold